# how to escape %2F in routes angular 5

Tags: html, angular-router

my plateform is angular 5 + Spring boot + Cassandra

I have paths saved in DataBase in this format:
`home/users`

Using angular routers I got the urls saved in databases to display them on the navigation menu...
So the probleme that urls displayed in html are not correct! 
the result is:

```
home%2Fusers
```

then I got this error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment:home2%fusers
```

any idea about this please?

Answer (score 0):

That is correct behavior (escaping special characters). You need to use wildcard matching /*page instead for the parameter if you don't want it to see path separators as separate route segments.

Comment: did not understand your answer, may you explain more please?